# Download go modules Nix OS

Tags: go, unix, nix, nixos, nix-shell

I'm downloading a program from github and trying to build it. The program is written in go and uses external modules. After running the nix script, I get an error suggesting that I use the go get command. How can I get modules from a nix script?

My nix script:

```
buildGoModule rec{ 
    name = "HH";
    src = fetchGit{
      url = "git@github.com:q/q.git";
    };
   vendorSha256 = "";
 
}
```

Error:

```
hh imports
        github.com/google/uuid: no required module provides package github.com/google/uuid; to add it:
        go get github.com/google/uuid
```

Comment: run `go mod tidy`, it should download all required modules